# How can I find if my website code has been implemented somewhere else?

Tags: source-code, search-engines

The idea is to find, through some search engine or tool, a HTML tag structure, or HTML fingerprint, which reveals similarly coded pages to a particular one.

A traditional search engine like Google or Bing will only look out for actual content, but won't give results for HTML itself.

I am aware some services, such as shodan.io, allow to perform a search on the network protocol level, without parsing the content. But this is the only particular example I know, it is a paying service and I do not know if it would allow this type of requests.

Comment: I can guarantee you there is nothing in your HTML that would be worth stealing. Not a dig at you or anyone else for that matter, just pointing out that this is nothing you should be worried about. Even if you came up with an incredibly clever and never-before-seen HTML solution, there is nothing stopping other developers from learning from your code. And that's a good thing!

Comment: Rebe Roth is mistaken.
Imitating sites can lead to phishing and scraping site data is not only more common that human viewers for most sites, scraping is also an enabler for many mimic sites that exist purely to host ads with legitimate looking content. It's also not a good look if they get human traffic intended for you because they'll think you host these ads or worse, they never make it to your actual site

Comment: Are you actually talking about the **code** (client- or server-side) or do you mean a plain copy of the **content** of the website?

Answer (score 1):

The internet is insanely large, I've a SaaS that tries to solve this problem and it's very important to realise that you might apply a few dozen techniques and learn tomorrow that you missed a site because they did something slightly different. This is something that a bunch of companies try to do with varying success. Its a problem that requires extreme amounts of processing power and storage. It's no simple answer for stack overflow

Most site owners actually don't need to find the copycat sites, they just need to deter the bots that do the scraping. If thats you try using recaptcha v3 (visitors dont see anything)

Answer (score 0):

You could place unique values in the [HTML Meta "Keywords" tag](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_meta_tags.htm), which *some* search engines will index.  (According to [this article](https://searchengineland.com/meta-keywords-tag-101-how-to-legally-hide-words-on-your-pages-for-search-engines-12099), Yahoo and Ask index it.)  If you put a truly unique string into your meta keywords, then you can search for it to find anyone who's copied your site as long as they left the keywords alone.

```
<head>
<title>My Cool Site</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="SuperUniqueValueStringHere, qlkzweamn" />
</head>
```

Comment: I wonder if this has any negative effect on SEO or user experience.